# AWS PostgreSQL give

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I've created on AWS a Postgres DB, set it to `public` for authentication, and added the firewall rule from AWS control panel to enable traffic from every IP to Postresql port ( 5432 ), but when I try to connect from pgadmin I got

[image]

As I've read I should add my IP `93.54.178.139` to the list of allowed IPs inside the PostgreSQL instance, but it's running on AWS so I don't know how to set it... Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Have you actually created that user in the database yet? Is that the admin user you specified when you created the RDS server? Are you even using RDS? You only mention AWS.

Comment: This is a password authentication problem.  It is already establishing the raw connection successfully, otherwise it wouldn't make it far enough to have a password problem.  Look in the server's log file to see if it give more details about what the authentication problem is.